# Angular Custom Material Theme not loading after v11 to 14 upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-material, node-sass, sass-loader

***Update** - solution at bottom of main thread post -*

Styles.scss

```
@import "./material";

$pace-red: #bb2d1c;
$green: #008000;
$red: #f00;
$black: #000;

body {
  margin: 0;
}
...
```

Custom Theme - Material.scss

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@import '@angular/material/theming';
@include mat.core();

$core-app-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette, A700);
$core-app-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-palette, 500);
$core-app-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$amber-palette, 800);
$core-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($core-app-primary, $core-app-accent, $core-app-warn);

@include mat.all-component-themes($core-app-theme);
...
```

I receive an error saying it cannot build the module due to the @use.  I have also tried using `@use '~@angular/material' as mat;` but that doesn't change the error.

[image: Error]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx-core-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr",
    "stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer wwwroot/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.2.0",
    "@material/banner": "^14.0.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.4",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^13.0.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "npm": "^8.18.0",
    "plotly.js": "^2.14.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.13",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-tfs-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.54.8",
    "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-angular": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.8.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what the issue is? I am including the styles.scss into my angular.json via -

```
"styles": [
              "ClientApp/styles.scss"
            ],
```

I have tried importing both styles.scss and material.scss (custom theme) to the angular.json but am having an issue where the first page on dev always loads without Angular Material loaded. Other pages have no issues and QA works fine.

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**
*The issue is that SASS can have issues with UTF-8-BOM encoding. I had to go through all my .scss files and ensure the encoding was set to UTF-8. My Material.scss was encoded with UTF-8 with BOM which caused the issue. I used Notepad++ to change encodings.
See issue on github here -*
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24227

*Thanks to @Anglesvar for the github link which solved the issue.*

Comment: "@use '@angular/material' as mat;"
"@include mat.core();"

Comment: @cfprabhu Same error, sorry I should have mentioned that in my original message.  I originally had that and tried using ~ in front and both did not work.

Comment: Does all of code in your material.scss file have the correct syntax? In other words if you slim the file to only have what you've posted here, does it compile or give a different error?

Comment: can you remove this line @import '@angular/material/theming'; and then check and let me know, please?   based on angular material documentation that line is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is a rather simple one. After Angular 13+, we don't need to import styles with tilde `@use ~() as xxx`. Make sure you use the proper command while upgrading to Angular 14. I found this git issue which might be of some help as well.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24227

https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-14.0

```
@use "~@angular/material" as mat;
```

[image: Compilation fails]

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
```

[image: Compiles successfully]

Comment: Although it was not the exact issue you mentioned, the tilda (~).  The github link you provides had the solution.  The issue is that SASS can have issues with UTF-8-BOM encoding.  I had to go through all my .scss files and ensure the encoding was set to UTF-8.  My Material.scss was encoded with UTF-8 with BOM which caused the issue.  I used Notepad++ to change encodings.